# Supabase SQL create in multiple tables on new user

Tags: postgresql, supabase

Using Supabase, when a new user is created in `auth` we add the `id` of that user to the database table `users`.

```
create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
security definer set search_path = public

as $$
begin
  insert into public.users (id)
  values (new.id);
  return new;
end;
$$;

-- trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

However, at the same time I am looking to add rows to another two tables. The first being the `organisations` table. This will have a unique `id` and a default in the `name` column as `My first org`.

The third table, `org_users`. In this table, we have the unique `id` along with the `user_id` from the `id` in the `users` table, the `org_id` from the `id` in the `org` table, and the `role_id` from another table called `org_roles` that matches the value in the `name` column of `owner`.

Here is a table showing the relationship between tables. Each column below is the table

| users | org | org_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id: uuid | id: uuid | id: uuid |
|  | name: "My first org" | user_id: public.users.id. |
|  |  | org_id: public.org.id. |
|  |  | role_id: public.org_roles.id |

I understand that this may be considered a duplicate from other questions. However, in those cases I have been unable to get their answers to relate in the method I require with my knowledge of SQL or Postgres.

I could handle this on the client simply and there is no downside to that but at the same time, I think this is handy knowledge for those looking to understand SQL queries.

How can I create the following in a single function?

- a row in table `users` with the `auth.users.id`,
- a row in table `org` with a unique `id` and `name` `My first org`,
- a row in `org_users` with a unique `id`, `user_id` from row created in `users`, and `org_id` from the row created in `org`.

  ```
   WITH users AS (
     insert into public.users (id) values (new.id) returning new
   ),
   org AS (
     insert into public.org (id) values (name ->> 'My first Org') returning id
   )
   insert into public.org_users (user_id, org_id) 
     select users.id, org.id from public.users, public.org;
     return NULL;
  ```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question? E.g. are you asking how to create the trigger on the users table to insert into the org table?

Comment: @thorwebdev, apologies, have edited the question now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH users AS (
  insert into public.users (id, email)
  values (new.id, new.email)
  returning id
),
org AS (
  insert into public.org (name)
  values ('My first Organisation')
  returning id
) 
insert into public.org_users (user_id, org_id) 
  select users.id, org.id from users, org;
  return NULL;
```

Managed to solve this with the above. For the `role_id` we just made the default on the table.